# Touching files in correct order

Tags: applescript, unix

This code touches files in alphabetical order.

I need to touch files in order it is in list_of_files, so first it touches file2, then file3, then file1).

Is there any other way to do this than to use repeat loop and do touch command as many times as there are items in list?

Thanks

```
set list_of_files to "'path/to/2' 'path/to/3' 'path/to/1'"
do shell script "touch " & list_of_files
```

Comment: It might help if you expanded on this a bit. How are you sure that it's running through the files in an order other than your list? Running `touch` with three files should take so little time that they should all end up with the same timestamps (as OS X doesn't record file timestamps more granularly than seconds).

Comment: Why not write all the file names to a temporary file, change the do shell script command to be `for $file in \`cat /tmp/file.whatever\`; do touch $ff ; done` and delete the temporary file?